# Cleaning up rows between employment status dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a file that has several dates and status codes:

(Example):

```
STAT_DT     STAT_CD  EMPLOYEE_ID
1/1/2017    A        1234
2/4/2017    A        1234
4/9/2017    A        1234
5/12/2017   A        1234
6/1/2017    T        1234
7/4/2017    T        1234
8/1/2017    A        1234
9/28/2017   A        1234
2/1/2017    A        7897
3/4/2017    A        7897
4/9/2017    A        7897
6/12/2017   A        7897
7/1/2017    T        7897
9/4/2017    T        7897
10/1/2017   A        7897
11/28/2017  A        7897
```

In order to make this garbage file usable, I need to be able to retain the MIN Status Date between each status change.
(in this case min dates to keep would be: *1/1/2017 A, 6/1/2017 T, and 8/1/2017 A* FOR EE 1234)
and delete all the rest.

So far I am drawing a blank at how to accomplish this, however I will update when i have successfully broken ground on a step in the right direction. All i can say is thank god for a test environment....

Comment: heh.. garbage file.  That's where they hide the secrets in the Gibson!

Comment: Lol. That's a great movie.

Comment: From the description I can't tell, if you'd like to have the data returned for just one employee? The sample data has 2 employee IDs, but you are describing an expected result covering just one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(stat_cd) over (partition by employee_id order by stat_dt) as prev_sc
      from t
     ) t
where prev_sc is null or prev_sc <> stat_cd;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would insert into a new table the values of the following select

```
select min(stat_dt), stat_cd, employee_id
from table_name
group by employee_id, stat_cd;
```

I just noticed your test data has the ability to go back to an old status. That means you need to add a self join looking for a different status code